# Getting/making a Windows VM patched only up to specific date

Tags: windows, virtualization, updates

I have a need/desire to obtain multiple windows VMs patched up to specific dates to use for testing malware and exploits - e.g. to allow automatic evaluation like "X behaves one way until November 2015, and differently afterwards".

Is there a reasonable way to make such VMs without too much manual labor? I.e. start with a "fresh" VM and configure it (preferably in a way that can be automated by a script) to install only security updates up until date xxx / version yyy, but not anything later?

Answer (score 0):

Just like WSUS, SCCM (or a similar product) would be an option to download patches en mass and assign them into deployment groups or packages for deployment. With a bit of scripting (or not), it could be very flexible for a variety of OS and build combinations.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: If I word it, "Use SCCM or WSUS to create patch deployments you can target against VM builds" - would it have worked? Yes. Same thing.

Answer (score -1):

only by using WSUS and per-machine rules it is possible, but I hardly beleive that you will be able to perform a clear simulation, i.e. install updates that are in cumulative ones now

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: This answer looks like comment, I totally agree. But I don't see any way to expand it because it is that simple. If there's some additional details you think that can be added - you're welcome to ask, I'll expand my answer gladly! My goal is to help people, and more comprehensive answers are better in helping others.